# How to prevent save model changes in a before_save callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, before-save

So i have to 1) not save changes but instead 2) save the audit with these changes. The second part is achieved by `send_for_audit` method, but if i return false in it the new Audit instance is not created as well as changes to the Article instance are not saved (there is the simplified code).

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base    
  before_save :send_for_audit, if: :changed?
  has_many :audits, as: :auditable

  private

  def send_for_audit
    audits.destroy_all
    Audit.create!(auditable: self, data: changes)
  end    
end

class Audit < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :auditable, :auditable_id, :auiditable_type, :data
  store :data
  belongs_to :auditable, polymorphic: true

  def accept
    object_class = self.auditable_type.constantize
    object = object_class.find_by_id(auditable_id)
    data.each do |attr, values|
      object.update_column(attr.to_sym, values.last)
    end
    self.destroy
  end
end
```

I've tried to add an additional before_save callback thinking that the order in which they are triggered will do the trick:

```
before_save :send_for_audit, if: :changed?
before_save :revert_changes

def send_for_audit
  audits.destroy_all
  Audit.create!(auditable: self, data: changes)
  @need_to_revert = true
end

def revert_changes
 if @need_to_revert
   @need_to_revert = nil
   false
 end
end
```

but anyway i got no Audit instance..
Any thoughts how i could achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

i've figured it out
i just dont use before_save, but

```
  def audited_save!(current_user)
    if current_user.superadmin
      save!
    else
      audits.destroy_all
      Audit.create!(auditable: self, data: changes)
    end
  end
```

and then i use that method in the update controller action